# Java Make sure library is in path environment variable

Tags: java

I'm developing a Java application which uses an external jar file which accesses a Windows dll. If I put the path to the DLL in a Windows path environment variable the application runs fine but I don't really want to have to setup this Windows environment variable on every machine I deploy this application. Is there a way I can set up Java application to locate the DLL without modifying the Windows PATH environment variable?

Thanks!

Comment: you would need .bat file where you define path and start your jvm and let user use .bat file to launch your application.

Comment: Had a similar issue,I too was looking for deployment of a SAR file on jboss,don't know where to put those .dll files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM needs to know where to find native libraries. You can set the property `java.library.path` when you start your application to include the path to the .dll like this:

```
java -jar YourJar.jar -Djava.library.path=path/to/dll
```

That means you would have to write some kind of launcher to start your application (a simple .bat file would probably be enough).

When the JVM starts the classloader caches all library paths, so it is not easily possible to change or add a path once the application is running.
If you really do not want to provide a launcher, you can use reflection to force the classloader to reload that cache at runtime like so:

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "path/to/dll");

// forces the classloader to reload the cache the first time a native 
// library is being loaded
final Field sysPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
sysPathsField.setAccessible(true);
sysPathsField.set(null, null);
```

Be aware of the fact that this is a pretty dirty hack though and that it might just stop working if you try to use it with a different JVM or update your existing JVM.

Comment: Your link is dead.

Comment: Note "sys_paths" hack does not work in recent JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use `System.load("/absolute/path/to/mydll.dll")` at startup.
You'll need to provide the absolute path to your dll but no extra JVM argument is needed.