# Can I put the library path directly in the code?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm testing with JNI.

So currently I jave my .class file and my .so file in the same folder, the program actually runs fine, but when I want to run it I have to write:

```
java -Djava.library.path=. filename.class
```

So that the .class can "see" the .so file.

Is there a way to avoid writing `-Djava.library.path=.`?

I've researched online about this topic, but I can't seem to find anything useful

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453541/java-make-sure-library-is-in-path-environment-variable Cheers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows the value of environment variable `Path` is used for System property `java.library.path`, so the following would include the folder "whatever" in library path:

```
set PATH=whatever;%PATH%
```

On Linux you can set environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, this adds folder "whatever" to library path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=whatever:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Note that you need to be careful about relying on environment variables, and these variables aren't used if the `-Djava.library.path=` setting is used.

Alternatively you could use `jpackage` to build executable version of your app and set `java.library.path` as part of the settings for the launch.